# Проблемы с паузой в Audio (html5)

Tags: аудио, mp3, html5

Здравствуйте. Очень нужна ваша помощь.

На сайте хочу разместить кнопку, которая воспроизводит музыку.
Нажатие - воспроизведение музыки. Второе нажатие - пауза. Третье - продолжение с того места, где нажали "паузу".

**Вот код:**

```
<script>
function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
if (!audie.src || audie.src !== audioFile) audie.src = audioFile;
console.log(audie.paused);
if (audie.paused == false) {
console.log('pause');
audie.pause();
} else {
console.log('play');
audie.play();
}
}
</script>

<button class="hello" onclick="StartOrStop('audio5.mp3')">Послушайте наше аудио!</button>
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
```

**Проблема в том, что этот код работает исправно только для формата .oga. Если использовать .mp3, то при повторном нажатии на кнопку музыка просто воспроизводится заново.**

Большое спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать решить проблему сохранением/установкой свойства `currentTime`: [HTML Audio/Video DOM currentTime Property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp).